# Slide Menu de Izquierda a Derecha en JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de hacer un menu que al dar click en boton del header de mi pagina se muestre, pero no esta funcionando, estoy usando la funcion **toggle()** No se que pasa que no se desliza como deberia, si se muestra pero no con el efecto deslizante...
Este es mi codigo jQuery:

```
 $('#btn-menu').click(function() {
   $('.menu--mobile').toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
   $('.menu--mobile-overlay').fadeToggle(500);
 });
```

y en la consola me muestra:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: k.easing[this.easing] is not a function
at init.run (jquery.min.js:2)
at u (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.k.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:2)
at lt (jquery.min.js:2)
```

NO SE DE QUE SE TRATA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que el error que te está devolviendo indica que la función no existe, has importado JQueryUI?, Si es así, puedes añadir el codigo html para indagar un poco más?

Si no es así importa JQueryUI y vuelve a intentarlo.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'>
</script>
```